# Keep only the most recent date

Tags: r, datatable

I have this data

```
data;code
18/02/2020;C106
05/04/2018;C107
11/09/2016;C107
16/02/2019;C109
11/03/2020;C110
04/03/2020;C114
18/02/2020;C114
06/02/2020;C121
```

I would like to select the most recent date for each code, like this:

```
data;code
18/02/2020;C106
05/04/2018;C107
16/02/2019;C109
11/03/2020;C110
04/03/2020;C114
06/02/2020;C121
```

I tried:

```
tapply(data$data, data$code, max)
```

But I received this:

```
Error in Summary.factor(7L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, after grouping by 'code', `slice` the row where the `data` is `max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
    group_by(code) %>%
    slice(which.max(dmy(data)))
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(data = as.Date(data, '%d/%m/%Y')) ~ code, data, max)
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses `dplyr` and `lubridate` to format the `data` column, group by the `code` column, and filter on the most recent (`last`) date for each `code`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(data = dmy(data)) %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  filter(data == last(data))
```